# Symplectic formulation of statistical physics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry

Does there exists a symplectic formulation of statistical physics?

I know that thermodynamics can be written in a symplectic language and of course classical mechanics is intrinsically formulated symplectic, but I do not know anything which tries to relate them 'symplectilly'. Partial results are also welcome!

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3472 "Thermodynamics and the moment map"
Mikhail Kapranov Abstract: We give a thermodynamical interpretation of the moment map for toric varieties... I put this paper on my table since usually Kapranov's papers are very insightful, unfortunately I did not have time to read it... 

Comment: You cannot go wrong with a classic, *Mathematical foundations of statistical mechanics* by A. I. Khinchin, Dover.  The word symplectic is never used in the paper,   but  one of the  first fact he proves is *Liouville's theorem*:  a Hamiltonian flow on the standard symplectic $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ preserves  the  symplectic volume.  In any case, it is an excellent read for a mathematician.

Comment: in a similar vein, one might ask for a symplectic formulation of quantum mechanics: arxiv.org/abs/1208.5969

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to read Chapter IV "Statistical Mechanics" in *[Structure of Dynamical Systems](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1461545)* (1970 French original available [here](http://www.jmsouriau.com/structure_des_systemes_dynamiques.htm)) by J.-M. Souriau, one of the pioneers of symplectic mechanics.

Given a symplectic manifold $X$ on which a Lie group $G$ acts with moment map $\Psi$, Souriau defines the *Gibbs states* as the probability measures on $X$ that maximize entropy for a given mean value of $\Psi$. He shows (thm 16.219) that they have the form
$$
\text{const}\times e^{-\langle\Psi(\cdot),\beta\rangle}\lambda,
\qquad
(\lambda=\text{Liouville measure})
$$
for some $\beta\in\mathfrak g$ which generalizes the "inverse temperature" when $G=\mathbf R=$ {time translations}. The rest of the Chapter is devoted to the study of these states; in particular when $G=$ SO(3), $\beta$ can be interpreted as a rotation vector, and the fact that planets revolve in a common plane as the equality of their equilibrium $\beta$s. See also *Définition covariante des équilibres thermodynamiques*, Suppl. Nuovo Cimento **1** (1966), 203–216.

Later Souriau developed a general-relativistic viewpoint on dissipative processes which explains why they preserve the mean value of $\Psi(x)$. Thus, quoting from [this summary](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2335767) to whet your appetite: "the first principle of thermodynamics [loses] its primitive status and [becomes] a necessary consequence of the invariance of the symplectic structure in gravitational gauge transformations." For more details, see *[Thermodynamique et géométrie](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0063682)*, Lecture Notes in Math. **676** (1978), 369–397 or [scanned preprint](http://www-lib.kek.jp/cgi-bin/kiss_prepri.v8?KN=197810025).

Answer (score 3):

I invite you to read the following papers about "Lie group Thermodynamics" of Jean-Marie Souriau. Souriau has discovered that Gibbs equilibrium is not covariant with respect to Dynamical groups, then he has considered Gibbs equilibrium on a Symplectic Manifold with covariant model with respect to a Lie group action. Souriau has introduced a geometric (planck) temperature in the Lie Algebra of the group:

[1]Barbaresco, F. Koszul Information Geometry and Souriau Geometric Temperature/Capacity of Lie Group Thermodynamics. Entropy 2014, 16, 4521-4565.

http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/16/8/4521/pdf

[2]Barbaresco F., Koszul information geometry and Souriau Lie group thermodynamics, AIP Conf. Proc. 1641, 74 (2015)

http://djafari.free.fr/MaxEnt2014/papers/Tutorial7_paper.pdf

More information at GSI'15 conference:

www.gsi2015.org

F. Barbaresco

GSI General Chair